# Scala views -- non-strict vs. lazy

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to create a "lazy" map of objects (actually, they are actors, but I am asking my question with a more trivial example).

Scala views are, in a sense, *lazy*. But their laziness is really just non-strictness. That's to say, the values are effectively call-by-name, which is in turn to say that the values are evaluated, when required, by invoking a *Function0* (a no-parameter function).

What I'm interested in is a collection that is evaluated lazily, but is evaluated only once. Here's the kind of thing I'm looking for:

```
val x = Map(1->2, 2->2).view
val y = x map {case (k,v) => (k,{println("Hello");v.toString})}
val z1 = y.find{case (k,_) => k==1}
val z2 = y.find{case (k,_) => k==1}
```

When I put this into a Scala worksheet, what I get is:

```
x: scala.collection.IterableView[(Int, Int),scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]] = IterableView(...)
y: scala.collection.IterableView[(Int, String),Iterable[_]] = IterableViewM(...)
Hello
z1: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((1,1))
Hello
z2: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((1,1))
```

Everything is just as it should be. Except that I don't want to see that second "Hello". In other words, I only want the mapped function (*toString*) to be invoked once -- when needed.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to achieve my goal? It's not super-important but I'm curious if it can be done.

Comment: what the difference between `z1` and `z2` ?

Comment: @rumoku no difference, he just wants to memoize y so that the map function is not called twice for each element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *almost* get what you want using a `Stream`:

```
scala> val x = TreeMap(1->2, 2->2) // to preserve order
x: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 2)

scala> val y = x.toStream map {case (k,v) => (k,{println(s"Hello $k");v.toString})}
Hello 1
y: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, String)] = Stream((1,2), ?)

scala> y.find{case (k,_) => k==1}
res8: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((1,2))

scala> y.find{case (k,_) => k==2}
Hello 2
res9: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((2,2))
```

as you can see, the first element is evaluated strictly, but the others are evaluated and memoized on-demand

If you make the stream itself a `lazy val`, you get what you want:

```
scala>   val x = TreeMap(1->2, 2->2) // to preserve order
x: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 2)

scala>   lazy val y = x.toStream map {case (k,v) => (k,{println(s"Hello $k");v.toString})}
y: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, String)] = <lazy>

scala>   y.find{case (k,_) => k==1}
Hello 1
res10: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((1,2))

scala>   y.find{case (k,_) => k==1}
res11: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((1,2))
```

If you don't mind evaluating the *whole* collection at once when you use it, you just need a lazy val and the collection can stay what it is (map, list etc)

```
val x = TreeMap(1->2, 2->2) 
lazy val y = x map {case (k,v) => (k,{println(s"Hello $k");v.toString})}
```

I don't think you can have a (really) lazy map, but I'd be happy if someone proved me wrong :)

---

edit: 
You can have a (sort of) lazy map by wrapping your values like this:

```
class Lazy[T](x: => T) {
  lazy val value = x
  override def toString = value.toString
}

object Lazy {
  implicit def toStrict[T](l: Lazy[T]): T = l.value
}

val x = TreeMap(1->2, 2->2)
lazy val y = x map {case (k,v) => (k, new Lazy({println(s"Hello $k");v.toString}))}

y.find{case (k,v) => v.indexOf("x");k==1} // let's use v to evaluate it, otherwise nothing gets printed
y.find{case (k,v) => v.indexOf("x");k==1}
```

The implicit conversion allows you to use your values as if they were of their original type

Comment: thanks for your (updated) answer. You've put quite a bit of work into this, which I really appreciate. It does seem to achieve what I was looking for (so upvoting). I'm not quite sure why you inserted v.indexOf("x") into the predicate but I removed that and it worked as it should. Bottom line, however, is that it's hardly simple (or elegant) and doesn't really improve much on the memoization pattern.Thanks :)

Comment: I put the indexOf("x") as an example, it's written in the comment: `let's use v to evaluate it, otherwise nothing gets printed`. If you never use the value somehow, you don't see any prints :)

Answer (score 1):

I would propose alternative solution, instead of `laziness`.
What if your `v` will be function but not value.
In such case you'd be able to control execution whenever you need without relying on collections laziness...

`val y = x map {case (k,v) => (k,() => {println("Hello");v.toString})}`

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any collection API that offers that kind of laziness. However, I think you can achieve what you want with function memoization as described [here](https://michid.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/function_mem/):

```
case class Memo[I <% K, K, O](f: I => O) extends (I => O) {
  import collection.mutable.{Map => Dict}
  val cache = Dict.empty[K, O]
  override def apply(x: I) = cache getOrElseUpdate (x, f(x))
}

val x = Map(1->2, 2->2).view
val memo = Memo { v: Int =>
  println("Hello")
  v.toString
}
val y = x.map { case (k, v) =>
  (k, memo(v))
}
val z1 = y.find{case (k,_) => k==1}
val z2 = y.find{case (k,_) => k==1}
```

output:

```
Hello
z1: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((1,2))
z2: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((1,2))
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was thinking of something along these lines. As you point out, it doesn't do what I really want, but it would do the job, if somewhat inelegantly :)